# Passing choice from ChoiceField not accepting

Tags: python, django, forms, web

I'm having trouble with django. For some stupid reason Django wants to say that I can't pass choices as a part of the form. It stubbornly says that

'User' object has no attribute 'choices'

Which is bull because Im not referring to a User object. I'm not sure how to fix that. I just need the choice selected to the view method from the form. Does anyone know how to do it?

This is the form...

```
''' Form used in medical personnel registration. Extends UserCreationForm '''
class MedicalPersonnelRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
#email = EmailField(required = True)
choices = [
    (Nurse, 'Nurse'),
    (Doctor, 'Doctor'),
    (HospitalAdmin, 'Admin'),
]
position = forms.ChoiceField(choices = choices)
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("username", "password1", "password2")
def clean_password2(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
            code='password_mismatch',
        )
    return password2
def save(self, commit=True):
    user=super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.clean_password2())
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

The view looks like this...

```
''' This displays the Medical personnel login form. Unique because of radio box for type of user '''
def personnel_registration(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = MedicalPersonnelRegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_user = form.save()
        if new_user.choices == Nurse: # TODO : THIS MIGHT BREAK BADLY
            new_nurse = Nurse(user = new_user)
            new_nurse.save()
            temp = Event(activity= '\n'+new_nurse.user.get_full_name()+" has registered as a Nurse")
            temp.save()
        elif new_user.choices == Doctor:
            new_doctor = Doctor(user = new_user)
            new_doctor.save()
            temp = Event(activity= '\n'+new_doctor.user.get_full_name()+" has registered as a Doctor")
            temp.save()
        else:
            new_admin = HospitalAdmin(user = new_user)
            new_admin.save()
            temp = Event(activity= '\n'+new_admin.user.get_full_name()+" has registered as a Admin")
            temp.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/') # TODO : Refer them to there home page

else:
    form = MedicalPersonnelRegisterForm()
return render(request, "main_site/personnel_registration.html", {
    "form" : form,
})
```

Comment: Well, as your comment in the code states, it does indeed break badly. What makes you think User does have an attribute "choices"?

Comment: I don't know. Only problem is that I need it passed as part of the form to instantiate a type of user. For some reason, it doesn't want to recognize it and I can't figure out how to make it accept that position/choices is a thing. Same problem occurs in another class with two CharField's. @Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a few areas of confusion here so it's quite hard to untangle what you actually want.

First, you should note where the error is happening: in the view, not in the form. At the point where it occurs, you have an instance of the User model. That does not have a `choices` attribute anywhere.

Secondly, even if you were looking at the form, you still don't have anything called `choices`. You *use* choices to set the allowed values and user-readable content for the `position` field, but `choices` itself isn't a field.

Since `position` is an extra field on the form, and nothing to do with the User model, you need to get it from the form data itself, which is in `form.cleaned_data`. So:

```
if form.cleaned_data['position'] == Nurse:
   ...
```